# Android fragment oncreateview is called but view is not inflated and there are no errors

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, layout-inflater

So I've done this a fair amount of times but I'm truly stumped this time. My fragment is called from my activity with no problems and although the `onCreateView()` is called, nothing at all shows up, still no errors. I've spent a couple hours looking for similar questions here with no luck.

Here is my `swapFragment()` method that calls my fragment:

```
private void swapFragment() {
        GenresFragment genresFragment = new GenresFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.flgenre, genresFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Here is my GenresFragment.java:

```
public class GenresFragment extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Customize parameter argument names
    private static final String ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count";
    // TODO: Customize parameters
    private int mColumnCount = 1;
    private OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private DatabaseReference mPostReference;
    String userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    private ArrayList<String> genreList = new ArrayList<>();
    private MyGenreRecyclerViewAdapter myGenreRecyclerViewAdapter;

    /**
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
     * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public GenresFragment() {
    }

    // TODO: Customize parameter initialization
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static GenresFragment newInstance(int columnCount) {
        GenresFragment fragment = new GenresFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mColumnCount = getArguments().getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mini_add, container, false);

        if (rootView == null){
            Log.e("TEST1", "Is Null");
        }else {
            Log.e("TEST2", "Not Null");
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    public void failure(){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Something Went Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnListFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnListFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnListFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onListFragmentInteraction(String item);
    }
}
```

And my fragment_mini_add.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#80000000"
    tools:context="com.nocrat.fanti.ProfileActivity"
    android:id="@+id/flgenre">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:text="@string/add_new_project"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/rLayout1"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView4">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:hint="@string/project_name"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:hint="@string/group_name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:layout_below="@id/editText"/>


        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/rLayout1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/create"
                android:textColor="#FFD700"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/cancel"
                android:textColor="#FFD700"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is my onClickListener that calls swapFragment():

```
addGenre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                swapFragment();
            }
        });
```

Here is my activity xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/flgenre">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:elevation="40dp"
                android:background="#ffffff">

                <include
                    layout="@layout/app_bar_profile"
                    android:layout_height="190dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/app1"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:elevation="20dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icons8musicalnotes64" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView8"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Genres"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:padding="5dp"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:background="@drawable/rounded_genres"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:id="@+id/addGenres">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_48px" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Add"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:elevation="20dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icons8resume64" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Bio" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/textView11"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:hint="Tell us about yourself..."
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView12"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="edit"
                        android:textColor="#FF00FF"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:padding="5dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView13"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="save"
                        android:textColor="#FF00FF"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:visibility="gone"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:elevation="20dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icons8trophy64" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView9"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Average Rank"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:padding="5dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:elevation="20dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icons8meeting64" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView10"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Previous Collaborations"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:padding="5dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what was the problem can explain me ?

Comment: Try to call addToBackstack(null) before replace, maybe it will add the current added, not the old

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos I just tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: @MohammadAli Basically, the "onCreateView" in my fragment is called, I know this because my "log" outputs a message but nothing at all shows on my activity, just as if the fragment is invisible.

Comment: post your activity xml code

Comment: @VamsiSmart I just posted it.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out the answer, all I had to do was change my root element(linear layout) to frame layout and it worked. Hope this helps someone. Thanks to everyone for their suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify you `swapFragment()` with below code by replacing `replace()` with `add()`

```
private void swapFragment() {
    GenresFragment genresFragment = new GenresFragment();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.flgenre, genresFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: Now please show the code from where you are calling swapFragment() method.

Comment: try by removing the addToBackStack() method.

Comment: I removed addToBackStack() but it is still the same.

Comment: I just tried the updated code but it's still the same :(

Answer (score 0):

Other people already asked for the activity xml, but for what I could see right now, it looks like you are inflating the fragment's layout in a FrameLayout that is contained in it's own layout.

Meaning, the container you are inflating into should not be in the fragment's layout, but in the activity's layout.

Unless I understood it wrong, you should not have the  with id/flgenre in fragment_mini_add.xml but in Activity_main.xml (or whatever the layout of the activity is)

Edit: in both activity and the fragment_mini_add.xml there is a layout with the same id you are trying to inflate into. I'm not sure if this causes the problem, but I imagine this could be the cause.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it before I posted here but it just gave me errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `android:id="@+id/flgenre"` in the first xml tag from your `activity xml` and `fragment_mini_add.xml`.

replace `tools:context="com.nocrat.fanti.ProfileActivity"` with `tools:context="com.nocrat.fanti.GenresFragment"` in `fragment_mini_add.xml`.

then, add this code to your activity xml to contain the fragment

`<FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/flgenre"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but while it does show now, the fragment just merges itself with my activity xml rather than go over it. The activity xml itself contains elements and I only want the fragment to show when the button is clicked. If I do this it will show every time I open my activity.

Comment: use `RelativeLayout` in your activity xml to let the fragment shows over your activity, and do transaction in onClick event like you already do, and change the `layout_width` and `layout_height` of `<FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/flgenre"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />`